# play framework ws call to https restful API throwing Exception on production

Tags: scala, ssl, playframework

Using Play 2.4.6 with WS to request data to a series of restful APIs but last addition I got an issue I can figure out how to fix.

In a nutshell I have some code like this:

```
    def testws = Action { implicit request =>
    try {
        Async {
            WS.url("https://someUrl").post(someodyRequest).map { response =>
            Ok("got result from ws")
            }.recover{
                case e: Throwable =>
                    log.warn(s"unexpected error fetching API ", e)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        case _  => Ok("error")
    }
}
```

On my local machine the .recover block never gets execute, however, in production the .recover is always running, the track trace of the throwable  is something like this:

```
java.net.ConnectException: General SSLEngine problem
at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.request.NettyConnectListener.onFutureFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:128) ~[com.ning.async-http-client-1.9.21.jar:na]
at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.request.NettyConnectListener.access$200(NettyConnectListener.java:37) ~[com.ning.async-http-client-1.9.21.jar:na]
at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.request.NettyConnectListener$1.operationComplete(NettyConnectListener.java:101) ~[com.ning.async-http-client-1.9.21.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:409) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListeners(DefaultChannelFuture.java:395) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.setFailure(DefaultChannelFuture.java:362) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1460) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1314) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:852) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:425) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:310) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1431) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:535) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:813) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1218) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1728) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:304) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1478) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:212) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:919) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:916) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1369) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1392) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1255) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:281) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1465) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:145) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
... 32 common frames omitted
```

I am using AWS to deploy the app.

I understand that the problem should be with the certificates ssl that the external service have but when test the certificates in

curl https://sameUrlthanintheapp # uses cacert.org as a CA

the certificates past the framework as is mentioned here:

> https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/WSQuickStart

can someone try to orientate me what to do? Thanks a lot.

Please.

Updated:

SOLVED = PLEASE READ COMMENTS TO FIGURE OUT SOLUTION AND EXPLANATION OF ISSUE.

Comment: Try to use `play.ws.ssl.loose.acceptAnyCertificate=true` in your conf (this is just to test, accepting every cert is dangerous)

Comment: Hey Salem thank you very much to trying to help me, I did try with the acceptance of any certificate, I am aware that this should not be done, but any way I just test it as you said, but still getting same issue than before, this is the weariest think ever, as the service seems to have a certificate from a well known certificate authority as test it with the curl from Play documentation, and plus putting the acceptAnyCertificate to true does not change anything, what I should do?

Comment: SOLVED: Ok guys just posting to inform if anyone is interested or have same issue. I figure out that the Keystore from java that contain the certificates for the validation of the ssl communication wasn't updated to the certificate of the service I was calling, so I have to update the java version on the container that runs the application, this solve the issue without the need of use the loose configuration or adding a copy of the certificate un the path.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then putting this solution in other words: the calling server was using a list of trusted certificate providers that didn't include the certificate that the called server supplied, so the caller could not verify it. For browser apps this might result in a "do you wish to trust" type message, but for server-initiated REST calls this, for example, this is not an option, so the call fails. For letsencrypt certs issued by a called server, for example, the caller should be on roughly Java 8 v102 for the authority to be included and the cert recognised.